# x_test.shape = 0 and array errors

Tags: python, arrays, testing, random-forest

I've been trying to split my image dataset but whenever I try to do so my testing set is always equal to 0 and I keep getting the "ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2."

```
train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_lables = np.array(train_labels)

test_images = []
test_labels = []

for directory_path in glob.glob("Desktop/brains/Validation/*"):
    fruit_label = directory_path.split("\\")[-1]
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*jpg")):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        #img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE<SIZE))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        test_images,append(img)
        test_labels.append(fruit_label)

test_images = np.array(test_images)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(test_labels)
test_labels_encoded = le.transform(test_labels)
le.fit(train_labels)
train_labels_encoded = le.transform(train_labels)

x_train, y_train,x_test,y_test = train_images, train_labels_encoded, test_images,         test_labels_encoded

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model=RandomForestClassifier()
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(oob_score=True)

model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```